# Gloabl styles are not applying to other pages (Next.JS)?

Tags: next.js, css-in-js

I am new to NextJS and I am having an issue with getting global styles to apply to other pages. Am I using the global selector wrong? Below you can find my index.js, and add-article.js file including two images that show global styles only being applied to the homepage.

Below is my **index.js** file:

```
import Head from 'next/head';

import Navigation from '../components/navigation';

export default function ArticleList() {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Head>
        <title>Article Vault</title>
        <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
      </Head>

      <div className='home-container'>
        <Navigation />
        <p>Home Page</p>
      </div>

      <style jsx>{``}</style>

      <style jsx global>{`
        html,
        body {
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto,
            Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue,
            sans-serif;
        }

        * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**add-article.js**

```
import Navigation from '../components/navigation';

const AddArticle = () => {
  return (
    <div className='add-article-container'>
      <Navigation />
      <p>Add Article Page</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddArticle;
```

**Home Page**
[image]

**Other Page**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom _app.js to get this to work. Import your styles here instead of index.js and make wrapper. As an alternative can also make a global layout and pass your page components as childrens.

```
   // import App from 'next/app' function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

// Only uncomment this method if you have blocking data requirements for
// every single page in your application. This disables the ability to
// perform automatic static optimization, causing every page in your app to
// be server-side rendered.
//
// MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
//   // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
//   const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
//
//   return { ...appProps }
// }

export default MyApp
```